# Как массово разрешить комментарии для таксономий wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, комментарии

Есть сайт на `wordpress` на котором для таксономий были отключены комментарии с помощью [плагина Disable Comments](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/). Теперь же понадобилось их вернуть, но деактивация плагина к результату не привела. Запрос в базе данных `mysql` на массовое изменение комментариев работает только для записей

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open', ping_status = 'open';
```

Как сделать тоже самое для произвольных таксономий?

Answer (score 0):

Полностью удалил плагин и потом применил вот эту запись - заработало!

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open', ping_status = 'open'
```